# How do I remove all tinymce instances at startup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tinymce

I'm dynamically creating and destroying textareas for this purpose. However, when I create a textarea and then an instance of it in tinymce--then come back to the page again, it doesn't work. I've found that the solution is to simply remove any existing instance of that same name, but I was wondering if it's possible to just do it at startup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

You have to make sure that the textareas or other elements for which you create a tiny instance need to have different ids.

To remove all tinymce instance you may use (tinymce3):

```
        for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--) {
            var ed_id = tinymce.editors[i].id;
            tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, ed_id);
        }
```

For tinymce4 use:

```
        for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--) {
            var ed_id = tinymce.editors[i].id;
            tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", true, ed_id);
        }
```

Make sure to shut down instances the right way when you try to reinitialize a tinymce instance. Otherwise your editor window could stay white or it is not editable at all.

Comment: this wouldn't work because the tinymce.editors.length collection is decreasing in size

Comment: If the length is 0, you will have an undefined index, I would rather with i = 0 and increase the loop

Comment: @SimonPaquet: corrected. But it is important to count down because the length of the array tinymce.editors decreases with every editor that gets shut down.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect. I have mulltiple Instance of TinyMCE and when I reload everything Ajax TinyMCE stopped working. So now I use this to remove all open Instances of TinyMCE.

Answer (score 14):

For me works this solution:

```
 tinymce.editors = [];
```

So, you can clear the editors array first and reinitialize the editor with init:

```
 tinymce.editors = [];
 tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    ...
 });
```

Comment: this fixed the issue on firefox. Great

Comment: +1. Only thing that worked for me (tinymce 4.3.13, firefox 47, multiple instances of editor in jquery ui tabs, where user needs to change tabs constantly and alter editor contents)

Answer (score 9):

My colleague Beni discovered a smart solution to remove all existing TinyMCEs:

```
if(typeof(tinyMCE) !== 'undefined') {
  var length = tinyMCE.editors.length;
  for (var i=length; i>0; i--) {
    tinyMCE.editors[i-1].remove();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm using and appears to work fine:

```
while (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
    tinymce.remove(tinymce.editors[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**TinyMCE V5**

Remove all instances with:

```
tinymce.remove();
```

More info see [this](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#remove).

Comment: Works for me thanks!, for V6 ( i cound't find docs for v6 ) i think its the same well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines in onload function of javascript or on saving form of previous instance

```
if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById(id) != null)
{
  tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, id);
}
```

where id is the id of textarea or input on which the tinyMce is present